# In Emacs, how do I display a message in the minibuffer with font face properties?

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock, emacs-faces, minibuffer

I want to display a colored string of text in the minibuffer, but when I use the 'message' function, the text-properties of are stripped.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Works for me:

```
(message "%s" (propertize "foo" 'face '(:foreground "red")))
```

You probably had `(message (propertize ...))`, which interprets the propertized string as a format control string, hence stripped of its properties.

Comment: `(defun lawlist-message (input) (interactive) (message (propertize input 'face 'font-lock-warning-face)))`

Comment: Is there a way that the color are preserved in the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: If you see the `#("foo" 0 3 (face (:foreground "red")))`, instead of showing a red `foo`, see here for [an explanation](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2332/11060), the reason is that the message is displayed, but then the result of the expression is printed, which hides the message. Putting it in an `(interactive)` makes it work as expected.