# Highlighted text in Emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, highlight, minibuffer

I'm trying to display some highlighted text in the Emacs minibuffer. I know it's possible because [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) does it when displaying argument hints. However, I can't see how it's being accomplished by looking at [slime.el](http://common-lisp.net/viewvc/slime/slime/slime.el?view=markup). Based on what I'm reading there, the displayed text *shouldn't* be highlighted (relevant section starts at line 3615).

I've tried

- `(message "%s" (propertize "test" 'face 'highlight))`
- `(overlay-put (make-overlay (point-min) (point-min)) 'before-string (propertize "test" 'face 'highlight))`
- `(with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window)) (insert (propertize "test" 'face 'highlight)))`

That last one seems closest to what I want, but the displayed text appears and disappears sporadically as I move `point`, and it has to be manually removed later. I've also tested the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742435/in-emacs-how-do-i-display-a-message-in-the-minibuffer-with-font-face-properties), and it doesn't seem to work for me either. The non-working solutions all do the same thing; display the text

```
  #("test" 0 4 (face highlight))
```

in the minibuffer.

In case it matters, I'm running Emacs 23.4.1 on Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're victim of testing with `M-:` which additionally to running the code, displays the returned value in the minibuffer, thus immediately overwriting whatever your code has done.

Comment: Actually, I'm testing with `C-M-x`, but the effect is the same. You are correct; binding the snippet to a key lets the first option work.

Comment: You can also test it with `C-j` in the \*scratch\* buffer (the result is inserted in the buffer instead of displayed in the minibuffer), or you can use `M-x ielm`.